# Can't acess ComboBox in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a combobox in an Excel sheet and named it "GraphChoice". It's located in a sheet named "Choose Graph"

In VBA I'm trying to fill it with data using this code:

```
Sub Choose_graph_and_date()

Dim Graph As Worksheet
Dim FormInfo As Worksheet
Set Graph = Worksheets("Choose Graph")
Set FormInfo = Worksheets("Forminfo")
Graph.Activate

Graph.GraphChoice.List = FormInfo.Range("A1:A3").Value

End Sub
```

I get an error saying Can't find method. I've also tried.

```
GraphChoice.List = FormInfo.Range("A1:A3").Value
```

Then I get error 424. Object Required.

The code is in the ThisWorkbook module since I want it to load every time you open the workbook.

Anyone knows whats wrong?

Comment: There is a difference between the `Name` property and the `(name)` property. Which property did you update to `GraphChoice`?

Comment: Is `GraphChoice` the name of the combobox? Is it an ActiveX control or a Form control?

Comment: I selected it in the excel sheet and renamed it using the textbox in the top left. The one that normally shows the cell selected.

Comment: It's a Form Control. GraphChoice is the name.

Comment: Enter Design Mode (on the developer tab), right click the combobox and choose properties. Then update the `(Name)` property to `GraphChoice`.

Comment: Hmm there's no "Properties" in the right-click menu. Only "Format Control". The right-click menu is the same with the Design Mode on or off.

Comment: In `Design Mode`, selected the combobox. Then click `Properties` in the ribbon. There you can access the properties and change the `(name)`.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry! My comment relates to the ActiveX combobox control, not the Form Control. My appologies!

Comment: I suggest using an ActiveX control rather than Form Control unless of course you *must* use a form control.

Comment: I changed it to an ActiveX control now and renamed it using the properties-menu but I got the same 424 error.

Comment: I'd assume `Graph` is not the parent object of the combobox, but the sheet it's on probably would be - assuming it will work as `FormInfo.GraphChoice.List = ...`

Comment: It's on the sheet named "Choose Graph". Tried `FormInfo.GraphChoice.List =`and `Graph.FormInfo.GraphChoice.List =` Both failed. Got the Can't find method error

Answer (score 3):

For a form control, you can use the DropDowns collection...

```
Graph.DropDowns("GraphChoice").List = FormInfo.Range("A1:A3").Value
```

Or, you can use the Shapes collection...

```
Graph.Shapes("GraphChoice").ControlFormat.List = FormInfo.Range("A1:A3").Value
```

For an ActiveX control, you can refer to it using the OleObjects collection...

```
Graph.OLEObjects("GraphChoice").Object.List = FormInfo.Range("A1:A3").Value
```

Or, you can use the Shapes collection...

```
Graph.Shapes("GraphChoice").OLEFormat.Object.Object.List = FormInfo.Range("A1:A3").Value
```

Actually, you can also refer to it using the code name for your sheet.  So, for example, let's say that the code name for your sheet is Sheet2, you could do the following...

```
Sheet2.GraphChoice.List = FormInfo.Range("A1:A3").Value
```

Comment: Tried the first one but got the 1004 error. The weird part is that if I rightclick the combobox in designmode it says `=EMBED("Forms.ComboBox.1";"") ` in the textbox where you enter commands. Is it really renamed?

Comment: In that case, you actually have an ActiveX control.  I've edited my post accordingly.

Comment: Yes sorry, I changed it to an ActiveX control. The last one worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that this issue exists, because ActiveX Controls have a different kind of relation (hence referencing) than other common objects (such as cells) towards the sheets. You can solve your problem by either using:

```
Sheets("Choose Graph").GraphChoice.List = FormInfo.Range("A1:A3").Value
```

or by changing the object properties of the sheet with your graph to e.g. **myGraphSheet** and then using:

```
 myGraphSheet.GraphChoice.List = FormInfo.Range("A1:A3").Value
```

Also if you want the ComboBox to be filled everytime you open it, you need to place your code in ThisWorkbook-Module (as you did) and in a sub with the following name **Workbook_Open()** :

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
   'code executed when opened
End Sub
```